# Rearrange $3\tan^2 x - \sec x - 1 = 0$ to solve for $x$?

Tags: trigonometry

I have no idea how to rearrange $$3\tan^2 (x) - \sec (x) - 1 = 0$$ to solve for $x$.

So far all I can do is rearrange it to form $$\frac{3\sin^2 (x) - \cos (x) - \cos^2 (x)}{\cos^2 (x)}$$

I don't know where to go from here or any other way to solve $x$

Comment: Just get rid of the sine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:
$\tan ^{2}x=\sec^{2}x -1$ so you only have to solve a quadratic in the variable $y=\sec x$.

Answer: $x=sec^{-1}(-1)$ or $x =sec^{-1}(\frac  4 3)$.

Answer (score 1):

You have a good start. From there you have

$$\frac{3\sin^2 (x) - \cos (x) - \cos^2 (x)}{\cos^2 (x)} = 0\tag{1}$$

which is equivalent to $$3\sin^2 (x) - \cos (x) - \cos^2 (x) = 0\tag{2}$$

since any $x$ such that $\cos x = 0$ is not a solution of $(2)$. Note that $\sin^2x + \cos^2x = 1$, so $(2)$ becomes

$$3-\cos x-4\cos^2 x = 0.$$

Can you finish now?

Answer (score 0):

We know that $\tan^2x=\sec^2x-1$ so our equation becomes \begin{align}3\tan^2(x)−\sec(x)−1&=0\\
3(\sec^2(x)-1)-\sec(x) -1&=0\\
3\sec^2(x)-3-\sec(x)-1&=0\\
3\sec^2(x)-\sec(x)-4&=0\end{align}

Now we have a quadratic equation, where $y=\sec(x)$:

\begin{align}3y^2-y-4&=0\\
(3y-4)(y+1)&=0\end{align}

So now we know that either \begin{align}3\sec(x)-4&=0\\
x&=\sec^{-1}\left(\frac43\right)\end{align}

or \begin{align}\sec(x)+1&=0\\
x&=\sec^{-1}(-1)\\
&=\pi\end{align}